# Assign multiple categories to Media Library upload

Tags: uploads, media-library

I want to be able to upload files and either immediately or after upload assign multiple categories to them. I have 3 different kinds of PDF document: Treasurer report, minutes, and newsletter. What I want to be able to do is have a user assign a document type prior to the upload and have that type translate into multiple category assignments per document kind, like this:

```
   Treasurer: Assign Categories A, B and upload file to media library 
   Minutes: Assign Categories C, D and upload file to media library 
   Newsletter: Assign Categories E, F and upload file to media library
```

I am aware of wp_handle_upload but have been unable to find anything showing how to use it to set the category at the time it uploads. Is that possible or is there a better way?

Comment: can you fix the indentation on your code? There's no indenting!  Also where is this code located? Is this on the frontend? Is there a specific reason to use `wp_upload_bits` and not one of the sideload functions such as `wp_handle_upload`? Are you asking how to fix your custom form or are you asking something else? Try to make your question as clear and fully self contained as possible, avoid ambiguity and don't assume people will understand or get the correct reference, if something is broken say how it is broken and how you tested it

Comment: Edited to ask a specific question.

Comment: You've removed a lot of very useful information and made a broader question that's even more abstract and ambiguous, _it made the question harder to answer!_ Can you edit it back in? E.g. your edits have removed all mention of a form which means now it's not obvious how you're uploading the PDFs, can you fix this? Re-add the code with fixed indentation, include the name of the file it's located in and where on your site it gets shown. Right now it looks like you're using the Add New media library page in the dashboard menu or the drag and drop in the post editor

Comment: if you don't know how to indent code correctly that's ok, but you should say so, don't delete it :( I can't help you if you remove/hide stuff

Comment: I am new here.  My question was modified because I have no idea what methods are available and I thought it was important to give overall objective first (I see many comments on posts with code here asking the code poster what they are trying to accomplish; as I was indenting the code as you requested, I realized I was proposing a solution that I wasn't at all sure about). No preference how the file gets uploaded as long as 1) it appears in the media library once uploaded and  2) gets assigned to specific multiple categories (as determined by the user-defined type of document) when it does.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to provide the answer so it would help anyone else wanting to do the same, but I was able to develop a solution, if it is of interest.

Comment: you can still add the code even if you're not sure it's the solution, an answer can take care of that, the important part is it adds context for why and how you hope to do this, and means people like me don't have to ask clarifying questions in the comments, context is really important. As for the answer, there's a heading underneath the comments titled "Your Answer" with a big entry box and a "Post Your Answer" button. Case in point, if you'd mentioned "on the frontend" anywhere in your question then it's very likely someone could have linked you directly to an existing answer

Comment: What does "on the frontend" mean exactly? Do you mean using the Media Library UI?

Comment: the frontend is your theme, what visitors to your site see. The backend is in `/wp-admin`. Media Library UI can also mean multiple things, you'd need to be more specific. The files you put your code in is also significant, as well as how it's called. e.g. your answer below uses a shortcode which would have saved a lot of time if you'd mentioned you wanted to display this to visitors in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, using a form to id file and set doc type, uploading with media_handle_upload, then post-processing using the attachmentID and combo box choice from the form with wp_set_object_terms:

```
  function myFileUploader() {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
            $doctype = $_POST['doctype'];
            $attachment_id = media_handle_upload("fileToUpload", 0); 
                if (is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                    // There was an error uploading the image.
                    echo "Error adding file";
                } else {
                    // The file was uploaded successfully!
                    echo "AttachmentID  is " . $attachment_id  . "<br>";
                    execute_on_add_attachment_event($attachment_id, $doctype);
                } 
      }
      echo '
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
          <label for="doctype">Choose a document type:</label>
          <select id="doctype" name="doctype">
            <option value="Newsletter">newsletter</option>
            <option value="Minutes">minutes</option>
            <option value="Treasurer Report">treasurer</option>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit"/>
        </form>
      ';
    }
    
    function myFileUploaderRenderer() {
      ob_start();
      myFileUploader();
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
        
    add_shortcode('custom_file_uploader', 'myFileUploaderRenderer');
```

2. Post-processor:

   ```
    function execute_on_add_attachment_event($attachment_id, $doctype){
    switch ($doctype) {
      case 'Minutes':
            $uploadCategory = array(946,974,933,923);
            break;
      case 'Treasurer Report':
            $uploadCategory = array(946,935);
            break;
      case 'Newsletter':
            $uploadCategory = array(946,975,922,937);
            break;
      default:
            $uploadCategory = array(946);
            break;
    }
    wp_set_object_terms( $attachment_id, $uploadCategory, 'category' );
    }
   ```